# ContextMenu detection

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mouseevent, contextmenu

(Apache Flex) Right Click brings up the ContextMenu, which I have changed the contents of.  All works fine except the MOUSE pointer was hidden to use a custom pointer.  The problem is my custom pointer does not move while the context menu is active, nor does the system pointer show because it is hidden.  How do I detect the Activation and Deactivation of the Context Menu?  An event listener would toggle Mouse show/hide to cure the problem, but I cannot find one for Context Menu De/Activation.

Comment: Instead of hiding the pointer can you not just set [`Mouse.cursor`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Mouse.html#cursor) to a custom cursor?

Comment: TY, Definitely easier than updating my own, but sometimes when exiting the contextmenu the auto cursor does not return to mine.  Mouse has to leave the window and reenter, or reactivate context menu and pick something again.  Calling Mouse.cursor repeatedly got ugly.  So, still need to detect context menu deactivation, OR have a stable way to poke the auto mouse.

Comment: UPDATE:  in constantUpdate function for game, mouse hide/show pings it, and keeps the mouse pointer as mine instead of changing to the arrow when over the context menu. Good Enough.  I'll upload it (PLODIAC, a planet star viewer) tomorrow to OstrichEyes.com.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Aaron's solution to use Mouse.cursor worked.  Closing.